# Send message to arbitrary vhost / exchange with RabbitMQ / Spring AMQP

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-amqp

I use `RabbitMQ` and `Spring AMQP` to send messages.

I have this snippet:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, key, object);
```

This works when I operate on a single `VHOST`.

---

I have to receive messages from 1 queue and resend them to N exchanges (on many different `VHOST`s).
How can I do it in `Spring AMQP (ver 1.2)`?

Is there anything better than manually defined `<rabbit:connection-factory>` (for each VHOST) and related elements in my xml context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We added support for that in 1.3. See [Routing Connection Factory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/amqp.html#routing-connection-factory) in the reference manual.

It's not arbitrary, but you can update the map at any time to add new targets.

Comment: Hello Gary. I have seen that already and we will probably update to 1.3, but not soon (*I dont know yet what has changed and if there are incompatibilities*). Do you have any idea for how to achieve it in 1.2?

Comment: You would have to do something similar, write a delegating connection factory and provide some mechanism to select which one to use at runtime - in effect do exactly what we did in 1.3. Another way would be a delegating `RabbitTemplate` wired up with a bunch of templates, one for each connection factory and add a `vHost` parameter to the `send` methods you are using.